# Observable: Skip second subscription if first one already running

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a simple code which returns either cached company or the company from the DB. The problem is that I subscribe to this observable from 2 different places almost the same time. This triggers 2 calls to the DB, so I would like to run second subscription only when first is done and cached value is already present. Is there some standard way of doing that via rxjs operators?

```
  public current(): Observable<Company> {
        if (this.cachedCompany) {
            return Observable.of(this.cachedCompany);
        } else {
            if (this.companyId == null) {
                return Observable.of(null);
            }
            return this.companyApiService.get(this.companyId)
                .map(x => {
                    this.cachedCompany = x;
                    return x;
                });
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - you probably want `publishReplay(1).refCount()` or `shareReplay(1)`

So there are two things you need. The first is to prevent duplicate subscriptions and the second is to cache the response. To accomplish the first you can use the `multicast` operator. It will create a single internal subscription to the source stream and share the result of it to all subscribers. Now this operator creates a special type of observable called a `ConnectableObservable` which allows you to call `.connect()` on it to make it hot.

However, most of the time people just use the `refCount` operator after it to turn it back into a normal Observable. The `refCount` operator will keep track of the subscribers to the connectable observable. When the subscriber count goes from 0 to 1 it will connect. When the subscriber count goes from 1 to 0 it will disconnect.

The `multicast` operator takes a subject or a subject factory as an argument. It basically subscribes to the source stream and forwards the responses to this subject which all of your subscribers are subscribed to. Its behavior depends on the subject you give it. If you provide it a `ReplaySubject(1)` for instance, then it will replay the last value to new subscribers. This is how you get your caching.

RxJs has provided some aliases for convenience. Here are the "basic" equivalencies:

```
publish() === multicast(new Subject())
publishReplay(#) === multicast(new ReplaySubject(#))
publishBehavior(value) === multicast(new BehaviorSubject(value))
share() === multicast(() => new Subject()).refCount()
shareReplay(#) === multicast(() => new ReplaySubject(#)).refCount()
```

The last one (`shareReplay`) really isn't accurate because of the nuance that it maintains the underlying subscription after refCount goes from 0 to 1 and does not release it when it goes from 1 to 0 until the source stream completes. This nuance probably doesn't matter in your scenario since you are doing an http request which probably completes on response.